# input radio button vertical and horizontal

Tags: html, radio-button

I want a form where someone choose a unique value of radio buttons vertical and horizontal (you'll see below what i mean). I know tha i can do it with `name`. In my code below you see same name in vertical.

Here's my code

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left;">tracking_url</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tracking_url" value="image_url"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_image" value="tracking_url"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="availability" value="tracking_url"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_price" value="tracking_url"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_final_price" value="tracking_url"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left;">image_url</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tracking_url" value="image_url"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_image" value="image_url"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="availability" value="image_url"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_price" value="image_url"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_final_price" value="image_url"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left;">availability</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tracking_url" value="availability"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_image" value="availability"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="availability" value="availability"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_price" value="availability"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_final_price" value="availability"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left;">price</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tracking_url" value="price"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_image" value="price"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="availability" value="price"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_price" value="price"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_final_price" value="price"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left;">full_price</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tracking_url" value="full_price"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_image" value="full_price"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="availability" value="full_price"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_price" value="full_price"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pr_final_price" value="full_price"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This is how i want to use radio buttons

[image]

but also someone can use radio buttons like

[image]

Is there any way to do it with html or javascript??

Answer (score 1):

```js
var col, el;
    
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    el = $(this);
    col = el.data("col");
    $("input[data-col=" + col + "]").prop("checked", false);
    el.prop("checked", true);
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;    
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
th:empty {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Twix</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-1" data-col="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Snickers</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-2" data-col="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Butterfingers</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="row-3" data-col="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

https://css-tricks.com/radio-buttons-with-2-way-exclusivity/

Answer (score 0):

The radio buttons within a row need to have the same `name="nameValue"` value. The `value` fields can be different for each radio button.

Comment: Also the radio buttons within a column need to have the same `name="nameValue"`

Comment: Radio buttons rely on the `name` attribute for groupings. If each radiobutton in a row has a different `name` attribute, you'll be able to click on multiple radio buttons per row. If you do NOT want this behavior, each radiobutton must share the same `name` attribute value within a row. If you DO want this behavior, use `input type="checkbox"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use checkboxes. And control if other checkboxes could be checked or not using javascript.

Comment: If you want to check radio buttons for each columns (second choice). You have to give for each radio button in column a diferent name. So radio button has no sense. Radio button is used just to select one value in several options. So I would use checkbox input, not radio button.

Answer (score 0):

**Here I implemented in Angular 7 input radio button vertically and horizontal**

*The Idea behind this is that with radio button we have name property which makes single select either by row or column but for both row and column. I placed the row in name and handled column with javascript whenever button will click.*

> This is HTML CODE

```
<section class="editor">
 <strong>Editor</strong>
  <div>
   <label>Add option</label>
   <button (click)="addOption()">+</button>
  <div *ngFor="let option of options;let i = index">
  <span>{{option.title +(i+1)}}</span><button (click)="deleteOption(i)" 
    *ngIf="options.length>2">X</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
<hr>
<section>
 <strong>Builder</strong>
  <div class="builder">
    <label>Question title goes here</label><br>
    <div *ngFor="let option of options;let row_index = index">
     <span>{{option.title +(row_index+1)}}</span>
     <span *ngFor="let rank of options;let column_index=index">
       <input type="radio" name="{{row_index}}" class="{{column_index}}" 
         (click)="check(column_index,$event)">
     </span>
   </div>   
  </div>
</section>
```

> And this is my .ts file code where I Implemented with Javascript

```
export class AppComponent {
  options = [{
  title: "option",
  rank: 0,
}, {
 title: "option",
 rank: 0
}]
constructor() {

 }
  ngOnInit(): void { }
 addOption() {
  this.options.push({
  title: "option",
  rank: 0
  })
 }
deleteOption(i) {
  this.options.splice(i, 1);
}
check(column_index, event) {

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(column_index)).map(x=>x['checked']=false);
event.target.checked=true;
}
}
```

[image]